# How to move Sidekiq (Redis) queue to another server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, queue, sidekiq

So we use Sidekiq as our queue managing system in our Rails application.
We also use Sidetiq to manage scheduled and recurring tasks.

At the moment there is around 200-300 scheduled tasks that will run anytime from couple of minutes to 30 days.

I would transfer just Redis database rdb file but due to some configuration changes, Rails project path has changed (hence tasks will not be able to run anymore)

What would be a preferred way to transfer whole scheduled tasks queue to work with new project path and manually is not the case.

- Ruby 2.1.6
- Rails 3.2.22
- Sidekiq 3.4.2
- Redis 2.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main concern was I thought that I couldn't just copy redis database because path of my project changes but as it turned out, it wasn't an issue.

Fastest way to replicate db for me was to first bind redis on old server to either it's IP or 0.0.0.0

and then on new server run

`redis-cli slaveof OLD_SERVER_IP 6379`

and then when everything is copied (copying is done in matter of seconds), run

`redis-cli slaveof no one`

Tada. Your Redis db is fully replicated.

Answer (score 3):

Use DUMP and RESTORE:

```
redis-cli -h source_host dump schedule | head -c-1 | redis-cli -h dest_host restore 0 schedule
```

http://redis.io/commands/restore

Comment: I had to make some changes to the above command and ended up with

`redis-cli -h source_host --raw dump schedule | head -c-1 | redis-cli -h dest_host -x restore schedule 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your redis dump file as you said. It's not clear for me why you are excluding that option.

Doing it manually (just create a ruby script for it), moving the scheduled tasks should be pretty easy. The only thing you have to do is moving the redis sets `retry` and `schedule`